# Proper usage of "status quo"

Tags: grammaticality, loanwords

I was attending my college re-union and a speaker just said that "Having an ebook reader is status quo". Apparently, it means that it is in vogue or in fashion.

I do not think it is the correct usage. But I am a bit confused. Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Status Quo* comes from the Latin *statu quo* which literally means "the state in which". Defined as

> current or existing state of affairs

To maintain the status quo is to keep the things the way they presently are.

Source: [Wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_quo)

So we have:

> "Having an ebook reader is the way things presently are."

Given that, I'd say the speaker is grammatically correct, but misusing *status quo*.

But, if it that were correct, you would have to use the article *the*.

> "Having an Ebook reader is the status quo"

I can't find that usage anywhere, either.

Comment: Even then it should be "the status quo"

Comment: @Mike Vaughan: I can't upvote @Martin Becket because he doesn't clarify exactly what *the status quo* actually does mean, and how it's used. And I can't upvote you for the reason he's just commented against your answer. Between the two of you there is a whole answer, but EL&U doesn't support 'half-upvotes'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. Nice Catch, @Martin Beckett. I've added that to my answer. So we have a "whole answer". :)

Comment: @Fumble: Just write, _+.5 . . . if you want to see the other .5, listen to me very carefully. . ._

Comment: @MikeVaughan: I guess I should quit while I'm ahead, but I can't resist pointing out (for others, if not you) that I personally can't accept *"Having an ebook reader is so way things presently are."* as grammatically correct. I know you can follow **so** with just about anything and pretend it's an adjective of some kind, but that one seems beyond the pale to me.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers hahaha. That's a typo. I'll fix it right now.

Comment: @MikeVaughan: It's still crap English, but in the circumstances I can hardly carp at you.

Comment: Well, effective and correct are very different.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the normal usage and I haven't heard it before - I would say they were wrong.
Of course if they are a particularly influential speaker it may become correct

"Having an ebook is the norm" or "Having an ebook is the standard" ?

Comment: Thanks! Why do you think it is not the normal usage?

Comment: First it should be "the status quo" (unless you talking about the band) and it generally refers to a bigger picture thing. eg. "General education is the status quo", not "using a calculator is the status quo"